# Movie compatibility on Android & mp4 problems

Tags: android, mp4, webm

I'm writing an app which plays small cartoon movies in Android.  I chose mp4 as it seemed to work well on phones, and appears to rescale dynamically for different screen resolutions.  Great.

The problem is that when I use Bluestacks the movies turn up corrupt:

https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/my_mp4_movies_dont_work_in_bluestacks

I thought I had a solution to this in that I just needed to resize the movies to 400 or fewer pixels wide using imagemagick, which fixed most of the movies but some stubbornly remain corrupted and I can't work out how to get them working consistently.  I've spent two weeks trying different things.  The movies play fine on my phone.

I'm now looking at "webm" format for the movies, which appear to work in Bluestacks but which doesn't work in Froyo and below.  I could ignore the Bluestacks problem of course, but it seems popular and I use it as a development emulator.

My questions are these:

Does anyone know why Bluestacks can't play mp4 movies properly?  It appears to be a rescaling bug.

If I put mp4 movies in "drawable" and webm movies in "drawable-mdpi" (which Bluestacks picks up) then which movie would a mdpi Froyo phone see?   Would it ignore the webm movie since it can't play it, and play the mp4 movie instead, or would it fall over saying it didn't recognise the type?

Comment: You apprently solved the problem by resizing the movie. And the first incorrect image you displayed in your post was. I don't think you can find a better solution is resizing is the solution. There must be a bug. What you can do is actually pinpoint the bug in Android or the open source project that contains that bug and propose a patch or issue a new bugfix request. That would definitely benefit everyone.

Comment: I would have a go at fixing it in the source, but the problem only appears in Bluestacks and I don't think the source for that is available.  Of course the bug might be in Android and only showing up in Bluestacks for some reason, but debugging that would be impossible because I can't update the OS in Bluestacks (as far as I know anyway).

Comment: So, as you said, if everything works fine and bugs in blue stacks, you can easier tell'em or just stop using this proprietary software..

Comment: Thank you for yor comments Snicolas.  Can you answer either of my questions?